# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

This is the one of the error, its saying I cant load config. I tried my maximum to fix this, it would be great help if you guys can help me. I have attached POM  file too. There's still more errros but I'd have room for it to be added.

Error is down below:

```
2021-11-06 15:46:13.006  INFO 22416 --- [           main] c.j.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication      : Starting SpringBootHelloWorldApplication on DESKTOP-7LJB9UD with PID 22416 (started by DELL in D:\Sem 5\ISAA\Java project\SpringBootHelloWorld-data)
        2021-11-06 15:46:13.008  INFO 22416 --- [           main] c.j.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
        2021-11-06 15:46:13.058  INFO 22416 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41ab013: startup date [Sat Nov 06 15:46:13 GST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
        2021-11-06 15:46:13.983 ERROR 22416 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
        
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:419) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:266) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:281) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
            at com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.main(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
      Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:107) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:409) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load cache item
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:79) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:116) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:291) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:329) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:93) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:91) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @65466a6a
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:54) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:44) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted

2021-11-07 08:40:28.868  INFO 28840 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41ab013: startup date [Sun Nov 07 08:40:24 GST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
2021-11-07 08:40:28.876  WARN 28840 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41ab013: startup date [Sun Nov 07 08:40:24 GST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:417) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1002) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.main(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]

2021-11-07 08:40:28.877 ERROR 28840 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@41ab013: startup date [Sun Nov 07 08:40:24 GST 2021]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:954) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1009) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:961) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.javainuse.SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.main(SpringBootHelloWorldApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
            <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        
            <groupId>com.javainuse</groupId>
            <artifactId>SpringBootHelloWorld</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <packaging>jar</packaging>
        
            <name>SpringBootHelloWorld</name>
            <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
        
            <parent>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
                <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
            </parent>
        
            <properties>
                <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
                <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
                <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            </properties>
        
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            
                 <!-- Tomcat embedded container-->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                    
                </dependency>
        
                
        
            </dependencies>
        
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                    
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        
        
        </project>
```

Please help me solve this as I don't know if the versions of java jdk and all is matched.

Comment: Hello, can you post your `pom.xml` (if its a maven project)? and what's the java version you are trying to compile/run your application?

Comment: Also have in mind that spring-boot 1.X doesn't support java > 9

Comment: hey i posted the pom.xml. hope u go thru it

Comment: Either upgrade your spring-boot version to 2.4.X or 2.5.X OR downgrade your java/jdk to 1.8. P.S. you edited your question and deleted valuable parts of the error stacktrace, please add them back.

Comment: hey can i get your email id? ill send my file over to you cause im not able to add the whole error stack tree

Comment: hey i added it, it looks messy but its the best i can do, please go thru it and it would be really great if u could help me out in this one

Answer (score 4):

You use Spring Boot 1.4.2.

[It requires Java 7 (or 8)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html).
It cannot execute on Java 11 or higher.

Comment: so should i downgrade to java 7 or 8? what should i do exactly

Comment: @user17341714 better go to Java 8

Comment: hey but isnt java 1.8 same as java 8?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and could fix it by making the following change in pom.xml

replace

```
<version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
```

with

```
<version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
```

Make sure to **Update Project** before running the application again.